# Adding multiple series to the spline chart using dotnet high charts in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using dotnet high charts with asp.net mvc3. I'm facing problem in adding multiple series to the spline chart.

This code basically updates the chart every second.

This works find for one data series. But I need to add multiple data series.

Please help me in adding multiple series for this code.

Thanks in advance

```
public ActionResult SplineUpdateEachSecond()
{
     List<object> points = new List<object>(20);
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
     Random rand = new Random();
     for (int i = -19; i <= 0; i++)
          points.Add(new { X = now.AddSeconds(i), Y = rand.NextDouble() });

     Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = false } })
            .InitChart(new Chart
                       {
                           DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline,
                           MarginRight = 10,
                           Events = new ChartEvents
                                    {
                                        Load = "ChartEventsLoad"
                                    }
                       })
            .AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad",
                                  @"// set up the updating of the chart each second
                                   var series = this.series[0];
                                   setInterval(function() {
                                      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                         y = Math.random();
                                      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                   }, 1000);")
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Live random data" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                      {
                          Type = AxisTypes.Datetime,
                          TickPixelInterval = 150
                      })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                      {
                          Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Value" },
                          PlotLines = new[]
                                      {
                                          new YAxisPlotLines
                                          {
                                              Value = 0,
                                              Width = 1,
                                              Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080")
                                          }
                                      }
                      })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
            .AddJavascripFunction("TooltipFormatter",
                                  @"return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                   Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                                   Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);")
            .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
            .SetExporting(new Exporting { Enabled = false })
            .SetSeries(new Series
                       {
                           Name = "Random data",
                           Data = new Data(points.ToArray())
                       });

        return View(chart);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: DotNetHighcharts has not been updated since April 2012. This means all the new functionality in HighCharts is not included. Also note that HighStock support is not available in this .NET wrapper. You may be best served to roll your own wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in [here](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/85324).

Assume that, there is a class that return series like below:

```
public class ChartsData
{
     //public static Series Hestavollane
     //public static Series Voll 
}
```

First series:

```
public static Series Hestavollane = new Series
                                    {
                                        Name = "Hestavollane",
                                        Data = new Data(new object[]
                                                       {
                                                            4.3, 5.1, 4.3, 5.2, 5.4, 4.7, 3.5, 4.1, 5.6, 7.4, 6.9, 7.1,
                                                            7.9, 7.9, 7.5, 6.7, 7.7, 7.7, 7.4, 7.0, 7.1, 5.8, 5.9, 7.4,
                                                            8.2, 8.5, 9.4, 8.1, 10.9, 10.4, 10.9, 12.4, 12.1, 9.5, 7.5,
                                                            7.1, 7.5, 8.1, 6.8, 3.4, 2.1, 1.9, 2.8, 2.9, 1.3, 4.4, 4.2,
                                                            3.0, 3.0
                                                       })
                                    };
```

Second series:

```
public static Series Voll = new Series
                            {
                                Name = "Voll",
                                Data = new Data(new object[]
                                                {
                                                    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0,
                                                    0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                                    0.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.7, 0.7, 2.9, 4.1, 2.6, 3.7, 3.9, 1.7, 2.3,
                                                    3.0, 3.3, 4.8, 5.0, 4.8, 5.0, 3.2, 2.0, 0.9, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4
                                                })
                            };
```

Applying to chart

```
.SetSeries(new[] { ChartsData.Hestavollane, ChartsData.Voll })
```